# TP-LINK-8901 modem does not connect automatically; only works in bridged mode

Tags: modem, repair, wireless-bridge

My TP-LINK-8901 modem does not connect to the Internet with "always on" (automatic) connection. I have to put it in bridge mode and make a connection in Windows to connect to the Internet.

Also, there is no configuration problem.

What I did:

- Reset the modem
- Update the firmware

Is there any way to solve the problem myself, e.g. through hardware or software? I can't have it repaired because the warranty already expired.

Comment: Arash, you've already asked about this problem. If you would like to get more attention for your old question, you can always edit it to include further information, or place a bounty on it.

Answer (score 0):

Does your ISP use pppoe? if so, you need to enable that on your tplink and provide the pppoe user and password.